# Wrong program logic for GridLayout

Tags: java, android, collections

Help to understand what the problem may be. I wrote this code and it has a description of the actions:

```
    int countPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            GridLayout.Spec buttonRowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
            GridLayout.Spec buttonSpecColumn = GridLayout.spec(j);
            TouchAction actionListener = new TouchAction(gridLayout, buttons, gameController);
            ImageButton button = ButtonsFactory.createImageButton(this, bitmaps[i][j], countPosition, paddingImgBtn, actionListener);
            countPosition++;
            if (countPosition < 12)
                buttons.add(button); // add each button to the collection
            // add each button in the GridLayout with the specified parameters
            gridLayout.addView(button, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(buttonRowSpec, buttonSpecColumn));
        }
    }

    gridLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout(); // remove the buttons from GridLayout
    Collections.shuffle(buttons); // mix the collection with the buttons
    Bitmap lastImageBitmap = ImageProcessor.resizeImage(getResources(), R.drawable.locked, bitmaps[0][0].getWidth(), bitmaps[0][0].getHeight(), true);
    lastButton.setImageBitmap(lastImageBitmap);
    buttons.add(lastButton); // add a button with a picture lock at the very end of the collection

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        ImageButton button = buttons.get(i); // get the buttons from the mixed collection
        gridLayout.addView(button); // add them to GridLayout
    }
    // do the validation that would be displayed correctly, but something tells me that this method is not for this!
    // in SWING, JPanel has a method like validate (), decided that it's the same here, but alas, apparently not
    gridLayout.invalidate();
```

The output image is not what was expected by logic, the buttons should have been mixed:

[image: not shuffle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the buttons in the GridLayout is set when they are created, their order in the list has no impact on the layout.

You can create a list with the GridLayout.LayoutParams and shuffle that instead:

```
List<GridLayout.LayoutParams> params = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        GridLayout.Spec buttonRowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
        GridLayout.Spec buttonSpecColumn = GridLayout.spec(j);
        TouchAction actionListener = new TouchAction(gridLayout, buttons, gameController);
        ImageButton button = ButtonsFactory.createImageButton(this, bitmaps[i][j], countPosition, paddingImgBtn, actionListener);
        countPosition++;
        buttons.add(button); // add each button to the collection
        params.add(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(buttonRowSpec, buttonSpecColumn))
    }
}

Collections.shuffle(params); // mix the collection with the buttons

for (int i = 0, size = rows * cols; i < size; i++) {
    ImageButton button = buttons.get(i); // get the buttons from the mixed collection
    // add each button in the GridLayout with the specified parameters
    gridLayout.addView(button, params.get(i)); // add them to GridLayout
}
Bitmap lastImageBitmap = ImageProcessor.resizeImage(getResources(), R.drawable.locked, bitmaps[0][0].getWidth(), bitmaps[0][0].getHeight(), true);
lastButton.setImageBitmap(lastImageBitmap);
buttons.add(lastButton); // add a button with a picture lock at the very end of the collection
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understood what the problem was. Answer accepted